# Migrating from Apache 2.0 to 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, migration, rewrite

We are going to migrate our Apache 2.0 to Apache 2.2 finally. I am only worried about the mod_rewrite changes that 2.2 might have gotten. Did anyone notice any problems when switching? Any particular problems with rewrites? Anything that behaves differently now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a lot changed of consequence, really; some reorganization of modules and changes to a couple defaults.  Nothing that I know of in mod_rewrite.

Review [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/upgrading.html) for a summary of the changes from Apache.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link. I only checked the release notes.